# Choose specific UI accent color

Tags: macos, system-settings, color, themes

[image: Accent & Highlight Color Options]

<sup>Screenshot from **System Preferences>General**.</sup>

In macOS Mojave 10.14.6 (current OS for me), and other versions close in age, the highlight color used throughout the system can be changed to any RGB color of your choosing, with "Other."

As you can see, the accent color lacks such a setting; the grey on the right is "Graphite" color. Can this accent color be changed in any similar way? The color choices provided are too limited for me.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There’s no option to choose any colour as accent colour, but there are more colour options available, introduced with the M1 iMac and macOS 11.3.1.

```
defaults write -g NSColorSimulateHardwareAccent -bool YES
defaults write -g NSColorSimulatedHardwareEnclosureNumber -int 3
```

with a value between 3 and 8 inclusive.

https://georgegarside.com/blog/macos/imac-m1-accent-colours-any-mac/

Comment: Cool! Thank you for sharing. Not quite what I was looking for, but that's okay. It's nice to know there are more colors if I upgrade!